# Has anyone integrated twitter with the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, twitter

I am a bit stumped as to my approach here.

I have an OpenGLES application written using NDKr8 using ANativeActivity and purely C++. Now i need to get Twitter and the OAuth api integrated. I cant use the C++ library as the support for cURL isn't there. I am considering using JNI and the Twitter4J library but was wondering if anyone else has tried a different approach.

Comment: You can also compile curl with NDK and then use C++ library.

Comment: I tried twitcurl as a starting point. It is a little outdated so I had to rewrite some things there. Bottom line: I got an access token with OAuth (having registered the app on twitter.com), but then the authentication fails. I mean I can access public (non-auth) methods like the list of friends, but I cannot update status. Just have no time to look further, but it is possible. Most of C++ samples for Win32 are portable to android. BTW, libcurl is used as a transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in response to Viktor and myself......

I used JNI calls to call back to java and did it using Twitter4J.  I had some fun with making sure the stats where handled and retention of the context when moving to a nw activity, see the nvidia tegra docs for the correct methods on this.

Note you can use the "clazz" member to launch new activities and cast it as a JObject when passing it back to a java class using JNI. Thanks the the android-ndk mailing list for some useful advice on this.

Comment: Please mark this question answered if it it. You should have use to "Answer your own question" link (at the bottom).